# Streaming audio receives InsufficietBW from server, what should the player do?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, flash-media-server

My streaming audio player sometimes receives NetStream.Play.InsufficientBW and shortly after that, the NetConnection is closed.

What should the player do in response to the InsufficientBW status?

Comment: Could the connection be being closed from the server side? If so, it doesn't seem like there's much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this topic but I think the solution would be to reconnet to a lower bandwidth audio stream if this situation occurs.